# Software solution for combining LANs over the Internet to simulate a single LAN?

Tags: windows, networking

Is there any software solution that allows people to combine LANs over the Internet to simulate a single LAN?

For example, I would like to play an old multiplayer game with my friends but it has no Internet support. We are able to play just fine when we are all on the same network but there is no way to join a remote game on an outside network.

I was hoping that there might be a way to combine our networks over the Internet so that the game sees us as all as being on one network.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

Comment: Check out [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like vtun, openvpn, l2tp+ipsec or any of the numerous vpn suites out there to set up a bridged network. This will allow you to pass LAN traffic between the remote networks as if they were on the same network. For this particular application (LAN gaming) there are several brokers which provide exactly this kind of vpn service.

Comment: do all of these solutions allow for combining at least three networks?

Comment: Depends on configuration, but all of them could be made to work with three or more networks. You'll probably want some kind of high-bandwidth vps to whom all endpoints connect which bridges the networks in a star topology. You might also try, as ErikA suggested, Hamachi which can work in more of a p2p mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spend time learning networking and messing with servers, run your own VPN. If you just want to play video games with friends... **Hamachi**.